# waiting for ajax to complete before next ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, promise

I am trying to wait for an ajax call to finish saving a model before saving the next model in the list.  I was googling around and saw some stuff about deferred objects which are new to me, and another answer that had a recursive function do it.  I tried the recursive method because it seemed to make a little more sense than with deferred objects and using `$.when.apply($, arrayOfAjaxCalls).then()`.  So that code (the recursive one, looks like:

```
    saveModel(index, numRequests) {
        var self = this;

        if (index < numRequests) {
            var sample = self.samplesToSave[index];    

            return $.ajax({
                url: model.url,
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                crossDomain: $.support.cors,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: $.support.cors,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("JUST SAVED");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr: any) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                },
            }).then(() => {
                self.saveModel(index + 1, numRequests);
            });
        }
    }
```

I call this like:

`saveModel(0, _.size(myCollection)`

It doesn't actually wait for the ajax call to finish in its current state before calling the next saveModel.  It basically just synchronously calls saveModel for each item in the collection in order.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing?  If there's a better solution with $.Deferred, I'm ok with that as well.  Thanks.

Edit: Sorry it meant to say saveModel in the last line of the saveModel function.  Was trying to get rid of parts that were domain specific.  And I'm using typescript, not coffeescript

New attempt:

```
    saveSampleNew() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve();
        var p = d.promise();
        var self = this;
        self.samplesToSave.forEach(sample => p = p.then(() => self.makeSaveRequest(sample)));

        return p;
    }

     makeSaveRequest(sample) {
        var self = this;

        return $.ajax({
            url:  "samples",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(sample),
            crossDomain: $.support.cors,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: $.support.cors,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("SAVED12");
                console.log(data);                    
            },
        });
    }
```

Because this code depends on other async calls from completing, I call this new attempt like this:

```
this.saveContainers(project).then(() => {

}).done(() => {
    self.saveSampleNew();
});
```

Comment: Is that [tag:coffescript]? If yes, please tag your question with it.

Comment: *Where* do you call "*the next saveModel*" at all? The only thing I can see is `self.modelDeferred(…)`. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: @Bergi: Looks more like ES6 code.

Comment: The code looks like it should work as expected. If you are new to promises/deferred objects, have a look at https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's why I asked. Afaik, from ES6 arrow functions with a block body you'd need to explicitly `return`. Of course, it doesn't make much sense to use `self` instead of `this` in an arrow function, regardless of the language.

Comment: @Bergi: Correct. But you only have to use `return` if you want to return something ;) My initial thought was something has to be returned, but I don't know how the code is called overall, so... not sure :-/

Comment: Yes, usually you always want to `return` from a `.then()` promise callback. In this case, it would need to return the "recursive" promise, otherwise the initial call's return promise would resolve too early with that `undefined` value. As we don't see the whole code, i'm not sure either…

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, if you want to do something after all the calls are resolved then you would need it. But even without it, the Ajax calls should be executed in sequence. Well... maybe the OP cares enough to clarify some things at some point ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, it should work this way. If you think it doesn't wait, please provide more information on how you call it and how experience that it does synchronously recurse.

There is one catch however with the recursive call:

```
.then(function() {
  self.saveModel(index + 1, numRequests);
})
```

The promise that is returned by `then`, and subsequently by your `saveModel` method, does resolve directly with the first ajax call, it does not wait for the recursive chain. The other ajax calls are still happening (sequentially, as expected), but are not being tracked by the resulting promise.

To get that, and properly *chain* the promises so that it resolves with the result of the last ("innermost") promise, you will need to `return` the promise from the callback to `then`:

```
.then(function() {
  return self.saveModel(index + 1, numRequests);
})
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.  It calls saveModel in order like before, but it doesn't actually wait for the saveModel() to finish the first time before calling it the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a for loop rather than a recursive call here, generally - I find those easier to read in this context.

```
saveModel() {
     var d = $.Deferred(); d.resolve();
     var p = d.promise(); // to start the chain
     this.samplesToSave.forEach(sample => p = p.then(() => makeSaveRequest(sample));
     return p;
}

makeSaveRequest(sample) {
    return $.ajax({...}); // make request using `sample` as data
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to achieve the effect of waiting for the first makeSaveRequest to finish before calling it again for the next object.

Comment: @Crystal then you might be using it wrong, can you show me an example? Are you sure makeSaveRequest does `return $.ajax(...`?

Comment: Ok I updated my original post near the bottom.  Can you please take a look?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok I added how I call it.  Let me know if you need all the other methods as well.  I figured that was more domain logic and could be left out.

Comment: @Crystal you're not waiting for it anywhere, how are you hooking on it being done? You need to do `this.saveContainers(project).then(() => self.saveSampleNew()).done(function(p){ console.log("Done saving all values!"); });`

Comment: So I see how "Done saving all values" will get called when saveSampleNew() is finished, but I'm looking for the individual calls to makeSaveRequest to wait before calling it again.  So when makeSaveRequest gets finished with the first object, then it will call it again for the second object and so forth.  Right now they get called in order, but it doesn't wait for one to finish before caling the next

Comment: @Crystal are you sure? It'll _queue_ them all at once, but it will _execute_ them one after the other.

Comment: It seems like that to me since my database objects get saved in order sometimes, but not always.  Also I have a log that I do in the success handler and I can see in the console that I might get two Posts before the log statement.